PMOS switch for protection
I have theoretical doubts about the operation of PMOS. Let's look at these two identical circuits in which only the polarity of 12V changes:

The circuit on the left where 12V are connected "properly" to the load has a PMOS that turning on ideally becomes a short circuit.
I cannot understand this passage:
I am used to reading that a PMOS turns on when Vgs<Vth (with Vth<0) ... however in the picture, at instant t=0, i.e. 12V input connection, we have: Vd=12V, Vg=0V, Vdg=12V and Vs=??V. Since it is an enhanced MOS, it is normally off so I don't understand how it can conduct at instant t=0+, how can the source be positive making Vgs<0 (as soon as I connect Vcc to the drain)

in green Vcc making linear dc sweep between 0 and 20V
in blue Vgs
in red the current on R1 (with direction toward GND)

"a PMOS turns on when Vgs<Vth" - a MOSFET is not a relay. It starts to turn on when the threshold is reached, but to turn on fully, Vgs has to increase further. Also, in the left hand diagram the body diode will be forward biased so the MOSFET will be conducting all the time.

This is a really good video that explains this reverse polarity circuit very well: https://youtube.com/watch?v=IrB-FPcv1Dc

thanks! @Finbarr

In these types of circuits, the MOSFET is "backwards" with respect to the source and drain so you have conduction through the body diode but also a low-resistance path around the body diode through the enhanced channel. Sure, the characteristics might not exactly match the datasheet anymore but you're in theory driving the transistor way into saturation and using it as a simple switch so it's kind of a moot point.

thanks for the reply, so if I replace pmos with a diode (with anode at 12V and cathode at load) would I get similar/equal effect?

Yes, but with a possibly higher voltage drop (Vf instead of I * Rds(on)). Note also that the PMOS is reverse polarity only, not reverse current, so if for some reason you also need to prevent current from flowing from the load to the source, then you will need a diode or an ideal diode controller + NMOS.

and why not flip the circuit by putting Vin (12V in the picture) to source, load to drain and gate to GND ? so you don't exploit the body diode but the negative Vgs

@toby514 Then in reverse polarity the MOSFET will conduct through the body diode, defeating your intended goal.


a PMOS turns on when Vgs<Vth

The definition of "turn-on" in the data sheet is usually something like 1-10μA of channel current. That's pretty far away from what is considered a turn-on in switching applications.
I'd rephrase what you've read as:
a PMOS channel gets considerably leaky once \$V_{GS}<V_{TH}\$
Also note the Vth can have a fairly wide spread among discrete devices of the same type, unless they came from the same wafer, ideally from nearby dies.
In other words, in practice, you should read:
a PMOS channel gets considerably leaky once \$V_{GS}<[V_{TH}+F(\ldots)]\$,where F is some random distribution, not necessarily normal. For back-of-the-napkin calculations, you can assume \$F=N(0{\rm\,V},1{\rm\,V^2})\$, i.e. a normally distributed variable with variance of about a volt squared.
